# How does BtcRelay ensure the transaction was signed by the claimer?

Tags: bitcoin, btcrelay

I noticed in the btcrelay docs that it asks for the tx index, raw transaction, merkle sibling and blockhash. It does not ask for the user to prove ownership of the key that created the transaction via a signed message so how does it ensure that someone else isn't claiming to have made the transaction when they haven't?

Comment: I'd guess since the raw transaction is included it is pretty generic and you can validate the ownership of the transaction if you desire to do so.